# execute other app method from reflection

Tags: android

I have one app A, and **installed it to device**.

```
public class A1 extends Activity {
    void onCreate() ...
    void onResume() ...
    void showToast() {
        Toast.makeText(this, "showA1", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

**And I wrote another app B, want to execute A1.showToast()**, but encounter NullPointerException at A1.showToast().

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    String packagePath = "A";
    String classPath = "A.A1";

    try {
        String apkName = getPackageManager().getApplicationInfo(
                packagePath, 0).sourceDir;
        PathClassLoader pathClassLoader = new PathClassLoader(apkName,
                ClassLoader.getSystemClassLoader());
        Class<Activity> handler = (Class<Activity>) Class.forName(
                classPath, true, pathClassLoader);
        Method[] mm = handler.getDeclaredMethods();

        for (Method m : mm) {
            Log.d("Method", m.getName());
        }

        Method method = handler.getDeclaredMethod("showToast",
                (Class[]) null);

        method.setAccessible(true);
        method.invoke(handler.newInstance(), (Object[]) null);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

I know that is A1 is not initialize, so "this" is null. Someone can help me about the problem?

Comment: im not sure  this will work try it by passing Current Activity Context to showToast() method as     `void showToast(Context context) {Toast.makeText(context, "showA1", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();}` and invoke it as  `method.invoke(handler.newInstance(),Your_current_Activity.this);`

Comment: ρяσѕρєя K is correct, Context might be issue here.

Comment: Thanks all.

But if I want to call other app(not wrote by me)'s Activity method (like onResume), and in onResume method has Toast or whatever, how can I do?